# Creating native Android push notifications for App built with PWA builder

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, trusted-web-activity, pwabuilder

Successfully created an Android app of my PWA using [PWA builder](https://github.com/pwa-builder/CloudApk.git).
Also Added web push notifications with the Service worker and web Firebase messaging API.

But due to certain shortcomings of web push notifications, I want to use the native push notifications using firebase SDK for Android instead.

Reading a few of these answers [How to use push notification for trusted web activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55426730/how-to-use-push-notification-for-trusted-web-activity), [Cannot understand how to open a simple TWA inside an app (using AndroidX)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57741990/cannot-understand-how-to-open-a-simple-twa-inside-an-app-using-androidx?noredirect=1&lq=1) gives me the impression that I need to have access to `Main Activity` and put Firebase `onMessageReceived` inside `onCreate` function.

But given PWA builder is a Node application that builds APK, I don't know where to start. I understand that I have to 1. Include the Firebase SDK & 2. Put `onMessageReceived`

But how to go about it using PWA builder?

Or Is it not possible at all? I need to create a brand new Andriod studio project and add `TwaLauncher`, from `android-browser-helper` as some of the answers mention?

Also posted this question on [PWA builder issues](https://github.com/pwa-builder/CloudAPK/issues/83).

Answer (score 0):

When you are generating Android APK, enable the "Notification Delegation" option.

[image: Push notification delegation option at PWA builder]

Comment: does this enable web push notifications or android native push notifications?

Comment: I didn't tested it, but it should work this way. https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/svgomg-twa/issues/60

Comment: @UpaJah it should enable only web push notification.